# Tabs content not visible

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I'm testing some very simple code to see how Titanium works, but I'm stuck in an apparently very simple step. Testing this sample code for the TabGroup UI element I cannot see any content (the labels) inside the tabs. 
If I dynamically add labels inside a tab they will work, but not if the UI elements are declared in the xml file of the view.

Reference: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/TabGroup

Code: 
app/views/index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup>
        <!-- Explicit Window declaration -->
        <Tab id="tab1">
            <Window id="win1">
                <Label>Label 1</Label>
                <Label>Label 2</Label>
                <Label platform="ios">Label 3</Label>
                <Label>Label 4</Label>
                <Label>Label 5</Label>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <!-- Tab included via <Require> tag -->
        <Require src="tabView"/>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

app/views/tabView.xml

```
<Alloy>
  <Tab title="required">
    <Window title="required">
      <Label>This is a required tab</Label>
    </Window>
  </Tab>
</Alloy>
```

Does anyone have a hint to clear this issue?

Comment: PS: tested on Windows 10, building for Android.

Comment: the default color for the labels might be the same as window background. Did you try changing that?

Comment: Also: I changed "Appcelerator" to "Titanium" for you. Titanium is the software. The doc you're pointing to is a guide, don't forget to check the reference too https://appcelerator.github.io/titanium-vuepress-docs/api/titanium/ui/label.html

Comment: @RenePot will try, thanks for the reference, I find Titanium online docs slightly confusing so that could have put me in the wrong path.

Comment: @Poochie is your issue resolved?

Comment: @mukesh.kumar apparently it was the default color. I don't understand why the same defaults don't apply for dynamically generated UI elements but I guess I will have to cope with that.